# How to load variable of file clusters to rsync

Tags: rsync

I need to sync some files inside the folder using rsync command. I need to pass file_store variable to rsync all the files that have to be synced. I created a small bash script.

```
file_store=(/etc/logs/ /etc/log_a/ /tmp/load/log/s)
rsync -rtu (how to use file_store)  user@192.xxx.xxx:/(how to use file_store)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run rsync once for each directory:

```
file_store=(/etc/logs/ /etc/log_a/ /tmp/load/log/s)

for d in "${file_store[@]}"; do
  rsync -rtu "$d/" user@192.xxx.xxx:"/destination_dir/$d/"
done
```

Comment: Thanks ams I figured it out started from ground, bash is so fun to learn.